# How to pass a variable to a parameter (in a function)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, parameters

I'm very new to JS and jquery, and I tried to find a direct answer but to no avail (most likely I'm googling the wrong questions).

I want to pass the variables x, y and d as parameters in function solution.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#form-send').click( function(){
    event.preventDefault();

    var x = $('#x-input').val();
    var y = $('#y-input').val();
    var d = $('#d-input').val();
    console.log(x,y,d);

    function solution(x,y,d){
        console.log(x,y,d);
    }
});
```

Comment: You'll want to call your function in order to pass them to your function i.e. `solution(x,y,z);`

Comment: remove your function outside of click handler.

Comment: If you want to call `solution(x,y,d)`, don't call `console.log(x,y,d)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this

```js
function solution(x, y, d) {
  console.log(x, y, d);
}

$('#form-send').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var x = $('#x-input').val();
  var y = $('#y-input').val();
  var d = $('#d-input').val();

  solution(x, y, d)
});
```

Comment: Ty! Simple answer and straight to the point. Will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
//function definition 
function solution(x, y, d) {
    console.log(x, y, d);
}

$('#form-send').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var x = $('#x-input').val();
    var y = $('#y-input').val();
    var d = $('#d-input').val();
    solution(x, y, d); //Function call   
});
```